# Optaplanner; How to use the benchmarkCofigTemplate.xml.ftl?

Tags: optaplanner

In optaplanner version 6.2, how to use the benchmarkConfigTemplate.xml.ftl?

I used the benchmarkConfig.xml and I get good results, but I want to use the algorithms with tweaking it and I understand from the docs that this is configured using the benchmarkConfigTemplate.xml.ftl, but I can't run it.

Comment: Have you read the docs? http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.2.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html/ch14.html#templateBasedBenchmarking

Comment: yes, I read but I'm confused how to run it? when using the benchmarkconfig.xml I run the Example.app class, but I don't know what to run in the other case. I copy paste the .ftl to the .xml and run the example but I obtain errors for "marshaling".

Comment: Marshalling errors means that the xml produced by the ftl file isn't a valid `<plannerBenchmark>`. Probably one of it's subelements is misspelled or something. In the future, we're trying to replace the marshalling error with an XSD validation error.

Comment: I overcame this marshalling errors, but please read the last comment in this page.

""Each one of these benchmarks can run alone, but when I put the three together only the default one runs. I want to run the three simultaneously, and that's what I understood from the constructor of the BenchmarkApp. Can you tell me what I'm misunderstanding?""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you copied the BenchmarkApp from the examples, you can run the template config like this:

In your constructor, add it as an option when invoking `CommonBenchmarkApp`-s constructor:

```
public YourPersonalBenchmarkApp() {
    super(new ArgOption("template", "path/to/your/yourPersonalBenchmarkConfigTemplate.xml.ftl", true));
}
```

Source: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/cloudbalancing/app/CloudBalancingBenchmarkApp.java

Comment: I'm adding it like that:           

         public YourPersonalBenchmarkApp() {
        super(
               new ArgOption("default",
                       "path/to/your/yourPersonalBenchmarkConfig.xml"),
                new ArgOption("stepLimit",
                        "path/to/your/yourPersonalStepLimitBenchmarkConfig.xml"),
                new ArgOption("template",
                        "path/to/your/yourPersonalBenchmarkConfigTemplate.xml.ftl", true)
        );
    } 

In this case it run the benchmark.xml only.

Is this wright or I did something wrong?

Comment: when I delete from the args the ("default" and "stepLimit") the ("template") works well.

I can't detect where is the problem.

Comment: Each one of these benchmarks can run alone, but when I put the three together only the default one runs. I want to run the three simultaneously, and that's what I understood from the constructor of the BenchmarkApp. Can you tell me what I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Please, read carefully: my answer doesn't contain the first two ArgOption parameters, and that's exactly why it works, just like you found out in the second comment.

Comment: The constructor doesn't handle parallel running of anything - if you want that, you can again read the docs: https://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html/ch14.html#benchmarkingPerformanceTricks (see `<parallelBenchmarkCount>`.. but you will only ever want to pass one config into the constructor, not multiple)